# Is there any number of rows limitation or data limitation for CartoDB "Mercator Plan"?

Tags: carto, google-maps-api

We are using Google MAP API V3 and CartoDB with "Mercator Plan" and having around 200 MB empty space. I am trying to visualize whole UK wide properties on the map with points and I have added about 1.4 million properties geo location into CartoDB table. Its working fine till now but I have added more data into CartoDB table and its going very slow as well as stuck some images of the layer on the map and giving the error "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request" in the console for these images.

Is there any number of rows limitation in table or data limitation for "Mercator Plan"?

Comment: Could you send us the link to your table so that we could check the error? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Iriberri, As its the official data so I can't share the table data link and the error comes on Google map while visualizing like this "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - .........../2015/1325.png".

Comment: That seems an error in the images and not a CartoDB error itself. Could you check if the images URL work?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the platform limits here:

http://cartodb.com/terms/#limits

Editing:

At the moment, the limits for basic accounts are:
Number of tables    1,000
Number of records per table 500,000
Maximum file size on import 150 MB

Although in the Terms of Service it's said that higher limits are available for verified projects, and they also depend on the user quota.

Nevertheless, I don't think this error is being caused by a data limitation, as it's a 400 error which refers to some image you may be using. We'd need more details in order to help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure, thanks! I wasn't sure about adding explicit information because terms could also change.